# Crown Chest Cards - Clash Royale

Tags: clash-royale

I just got into Arena 7, and unlocked my crown chest after the same battle, will my crown chest have the chance of giving Arena 6- Cards only or will it count as an Arena 7 crown chest?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are *totally* mistaken here.

According to Supercell, crown chest or any type of chest will always give the cards of all previous arenas. (Even of training camp). Moving to an arena, if promoted, will just add the possibilities of getting the cards of that arena. But, if demoted, reduce the number of possibilities of getting the cards of the arena, you are demoted from. If you are in Arena 2, for example, and you get demoted to Arena 1, you will no longer get the cards of Arena 2, but you will still get the cards of both Arena 1 and Training Camp.

Comment: He's asking if his chest will be arena 6 or arena 7 as he used to be 6 and just got into 7 with his last win. Which is already answered here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259796/which-arena-do-free-and-crown-chests-use-when-determining-the-cards-you-will-get